# What is a prosthetic group of protein? What are prosthetic groups?

Tags: biochemistry

I have found this term while I studying the topic of ETS in respiration in plants.

Answer (score 3):

A prosthetic group is a smaller organic molecule strongly bound to a protein. Typical examples are

- **haemoglobin** (bound to haeme)
- **biotin** (bound to carboxylases)
- **flavines** (bound to flavoproteines)